# altair - aligning tick marks with center of bars in bar plot

Tags: bar-chart, altair

How do I center tick marks in the middle of the bars of a bar chart?

[image]

```
title = 'Submissions from Aug 2018 to Feb 2020 by Month'
chart = alt.Chart(df_US).mark_bar(size = 25,
         color = 'black').encode(
    x=alt.X('yearmonth(Time_Received):T',
            axis =alt.Axis(format = "%b%y", 
                           tickCount = 20,
                           tickBand = 'center')),
    y='count(Time_Received)'
).configure_axisX(  tickBand = 'center'
).properties(
    width = 900,
    title  = title
).configure_axis(
    grid=False
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `'yearmonth(Time_Received):T'` to `'yearmonth(Time_Received):O'`: this will make it an ordinal (i.e. ordered categorical) encoding, and the labels will appear by default at the center of each category.

Comment: Jake: Much appreciated !

Comment: Your suggestion worked well. OOTH, is it possible to change the frequency of x axis tick labels, in the event that this might be preferred in some use cases?